# Dynamic Table in asp.net design

Tags: c#, asp.net

I built recently a table using c# and asp.net and I was facing design issues.

```
string name = Request.QueryString["name"];
    AnimalsDB animal = new AnimalsDB();
    DataSet ds = animal.GetFactByName(name);
        TableRow rw = new TableRow();
        TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
        Label l1 = new Label();
        l1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AName"].ToString();
        Image image = new Image();
        image.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Pic"].ToString();
        image.Width = 250;
        image.Height = 250;

        Label l2 = new Label();
        l2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fact"].ToString();
        tc1.Width= 200;
        tc1.Controls.Add(l1);
        tc1.Controls.Add(image);
        tc1.Controls.Add(l2);
        rw.Cells.Add(tc1);
        Table3.Rows.Add(rw);
```

The table is bit unorganized all the details appears on one line, do you have any idea how to sort it and organize the details.
(In my case I want to show the lable1 break-line image and break-line then the 2nd lable).

Comment: If there is only one animal... what do you need a table for? [<asp:Repeater>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4) could be convenient here.

Comment: I thought about it though and tried by using Response.Write build succeed but unfortunately the results weren't satisfied. ,@MikeSmithDev as you can see first it requests a name which is obviously come from different page. the consumer should choose a name and then the details must be shown.

Comment: yes, but tables are usually used for tabular data. If you just need to load in a picture and a "fact" string there are easier ways to do it... like just using `<asp:Label` and `<asp:Image`

Comment: Look at data-bound controls such as the Repeater or GridView - they're not the most elegant, but they're way better than all that code....

Comment: Yes you are right, what I'm going to do is add further infos(labels) for sure. meanwhile I'm trying to organize it. as well as I must pass parameters afterwards in that case it is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have to display is three pieces of information, try something like this for your front end:

```
<h3><asp:Label ID="_animalName" runat="server"></asp:Label></h3>
<asp:Image ID="_animalImg" runat="server" />
<p><asp:Label ID="_animalFact" runat="server"></asp:Label></p>
```

And then your code behind:

```
_animalName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AName"].ToString();
_animalImg.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Pic"].ToString();
_animalFact.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fact"].ToString();
```

Comment: omg it is indeed easy how I haven't thought about it.. thanks!